# User Signup Workflow in API 3.1.0 and BPS (EI 6.6.0)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I configured a User Signup Workflow in API 3.1.0 and BPS (EI 6.6.0) by following article from

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/customizations/adding-a-user-signup-workflow/

when i create a user using self-registration from API devportal, I get a message as "User registration completed successfully". instead of showing *User account awaiting Administrator approval* (i have seen this pop up in earlier version of API M)
[image]

Note:

1. Admin receives Approval Task to approve creation of a user in API Admin Portal (as expected).
2. User will not be able to access until admin approve from Admin portal (as expected)

Is there any further configuration to be done to show the proper message on user sign up as *User account awaiting Administrator approval* ?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any other configurations to do to customise the UI message, seems like this is a UI issue can you create an issue [1] - https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues

Comment: @dushansilva - https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/8660